# How to extract data from nested JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @CONTACTS varchar(max)
SET @CONTACTS = 
N'[
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"RWILS351\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EKANOUS\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"RLAESCH1\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"RWILS351\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EKANOUS\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"OINES\"},{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"YSEGARRA\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"OINES\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"TISMAIL3\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DBELL30\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DBELL30\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DBELL30\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DBELL30\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2},{\"pmtGroup\":5}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2},{\"pmtGroup\":5}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":1,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\"},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"DSANGINE\",\"idAttribute\":[{\"pmtGroup\":2}]},{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"EDESMET\"},{\"idRole\":126,\"cdsid\":\"NSPENC16\"}]"},
{"contacts":"[{\"idRole\":3,\"cdsid\":\"THERMANN\"}]"}]'

SELECT d.idRole, d.cdsid,e.pmtGroup
FROM  OPENJSON (@CONTACTS)
WITH (
    contacts nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as c 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (c.contacts) 
WITH (
    idRole INT '$.idRole',
    cdsid NVARCHAR(50) '$.cdsid',
    idAttribute NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.idAttribute' AS JSON
) as d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.idAttribute)
WITH (
    pmtGroup NVARCHAR(8) '$.pmtGroup'
) as e;
```

I need to get the values idRole, cdsid, pmtGroup from the JSON. What am I missing in my query? I did some research and I tried the cross apply but no data is being returned

Comment: Although it's JSON it's probably not the JSON that you're expecting. Each `"contacts"` property is a JSON string, not an array of objects like you're trying to query. i.e.: remove the `AS JSON` from `contacts nvarchar(max) AS JSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value contained in `contacts` is not a JSON object, it's a string containing a *serialized* JSON object.

So you need to remove `AS JSON` to retrieve it.

Furthermore, if you want to get the objects which have no `pmtGroup` you need `OUTER APPLY`

```sql
SELECT d.idRole, d.cdsid,e.pmtGroup
FROM  OPENJSON (@CONTACTS)
WITH (
    contacts nvarchar(max)
) as c 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (c.contacts) 
WITH (
    idRole INT,
    cdsid NVARCHAR(50),
    idAttribute NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) as d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.idAttribute)
WITH (
    pmtGroup NVARCHAR(8)
) as e;
```

Alternatively you can just use a path `$.idAttribute[0].pmtGroup`

```sql
SELECT d.idRole, d.cdsid,d.pmtGroup
FROM  OPENJSON (@CONTACTS)
WITH (
    contacts nvarchar(max)
) as c 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (c.contacts) 
WITH (
    idRole INT,
    cdsid NVARCHAR(50),
    pmtGroup NVARCHAR(8) '$.idAttribute[0].pmtGroup'
) as d;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3aa42bbdeeb889569099ebab1b853f0a)

Answer (score 1):

first, is your are using `openjson` so you should supply correctly formatted `json` data. Add this line to format your data before your operation.

also, no need to terminate `"` since this is a recognized sql character.

```
SET @CONTACTS= REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@CONTACTS, '\', ''), '"[', '['), ']"', ']')
```

[image]

Comment: The JSON from the question is valid. As @AlwaysLearning explained, the solution is to remove `... AS JSON` from the first `OPENJSON()` call.

Comment: @Zhorov, yes, its a valid json data, but "contacts":"this is considered to be string value not json data" value for "contacts" is treated as string not json data.